# Handle application's EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE & EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY events

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am trying to intercept `event_object_create` and `event_object_destroy` events through following code:

```
class NameChangeTracker
{
private const uint EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE = 0x00008000;
private const uint EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY = 0x00008001;
private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;

//DLL imports

private static WinEventDelegate procDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(NameChangeTracker.WinEventProc);

private delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

private static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
  if(idObject==0 && idChild==0)
  {
    if(hwnd.ToInt32() == getspotify().ToInt32())
    {
      switch(eventType)
      {
        case EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE:
        Console.WriteLine("inside create case"); 
        break;
        case EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY:
        Console.WriteLine("inside destroy case"); 
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Inside `main` method

```
public static void Main()
{
   NameChangeTracker tracker = new NameChangeTracker();
   IntPtr hwnd = tracker.getspotify(); // returns hwnd using "FindWindow()" method.
   int num = tracker.getprocessid(hwnd); //returns processid using "GetWindowThreadProcessId()" method.

   IntPtr hWinEventHook = SetWinEventHook(0x00008000,0x00008001,IntPtr.Zero, procDelegate, 0, 0, 0);

   Message msg = new Message();
   while(GetMessage(ref msg,hwnd,0,0))

   UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook);
}
}
```

My above code captures the event when I manually close my application(Spotify) and prints a combination of `inside create case` and `inside destroy case` but when I `restart` my application it prints nothing in the console.

So, how do i make sure that my program continously listen for `create & destroy` events fired from `Application(Spotify)` and is the above mentioned approach correct approach.

Here is my [ConsoleOutput](http://pastebin.com/LMX9hEXH).

**EDIT-1**

So, I changed `idProcess` paramater to listen to events from all process. But my program now only prints `inside create case` when I start my application it prints nothing when I manually close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's likely happening here is that when you restart the target app (Spotify), it gets a new Process ID - so your code, which is still listening to the old process ID - ignores it.

You can't change the PID you're listening to events from, so you basically have two choices:

- listen to events from all processes, all the time, or
- listen to events from a specific process, and when it dies, listen to create events from *all* processes, checking to see if any if any of the Create events are for a top-level HWND that's from the process you care about - and then listen to just that one. (Be careful, as there's a potential race condition here; after you get the destroy event that tells you that the old instance has disappeared, a new instance could get created before you start listening to events from all processes, so you should do a sweep of all top-level HWNDs after you start listening to be on the safe side.)

If this is just a utility for personal use, the simplest thing might be to always just listen to events from all processes - but still only listen to the few types of events you care about, and then see if there's actually any performance issues. If not, and it runs fine without any apparent effect on system performance, you're done!

(For a more professional approach, you might want to measure just how many surplus messages you're getting that you're ignoring and otehrwise get more data to determine if it could potentially be a performance issue or not. Create events don't happen all that often when the UI is in steady-state, so it may not be all that of an issue - but you can get a flurry of them when an app is opened.)

Comment: So, where should I inject the code that makes sure my program is always listening to events from all the processes.

Comment: @Noob: A quick read of the parameters to [SetWinEventProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) will tell you the answer to that.

Comment: I changed the `idProcess` to `0` to listen to all processes. Please check my edit.

Comment: That's probably because you're now not filtering properly: you get the DESTROY event just *after* Spotify is destroyed, and since it's no longer present, getspotify() likely isn't finding any window - there's no longer a spotify window to find! Instead perhaps you can cache the hwnd at create, and look for that in the destroy, which means you need to filter differently for create vs destroy.